# jQuery.get() returns Apache server error 3010

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, get

Here's the code:

```
jQuery.post('/assets/api/addToPicks.php', {imagePath: theImagePath, clientPath: theClientPath}, function() {
    jQuery.get('/site/templates/snippetServer.php', function(data) {
        jQuery('#picks').html(data);
    });
});
```

The first call to /assets/api/addToPicks.php works fine (I've tried it all by itself and get no error).

But the second call to /site/templates/snippetServer.php generates a consistent error (even when called by itself, separate from the jQuery.post()):

```
http://www.brp.dev/site/templates/snippetServer.php    301 Moved Permanently
```

Both files do exist at those paths.

I am stumped.

Bob

Comment: That's a redirect, not an error.

Comment: See if this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1534662/1628832

Comment: @Slaks Yes, the 301 is not a true error. But the redirect keeps the code from working and I wouldn't expect to get a redirect when the file is where I called it and has not moved.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a similar mistake I've [replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009650/can-you-help-me-get-a-spinner-to-display-in-a-rails-3-2-jquery-app/17009939#17009939) a few mins ago.
Basically you are calling a `jQuery.get()` after a `jQuery.get()` which makes two ajax calls.

As per your code you should be able to serve one request from server side `addToPicks.php` OR `snippetServer.php` and make a single call deciding whether it should be by `GET` or `POST`.

For your case I think [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-completeresponseText--textStatus--XMLHttpRequest) method should be the best solution:

```
jQuery('#picks').load('/assets/api/your_one_file_serving_the_html.php', {imagePath: theImagePath, clientPath: theClientPath});
```

Comment: Hmmm. But even when jQuery.get('/site/templates/snippetServer.php', function(data) { jQuery('#picks').html(data); }); is called by itself, I still get the 301. And if I combine the functions, that's the one I need to combine them in.

Comment: Is your page at snippetServer.php able to serve http GET request? You should be able to get in the browser /site/templates/snippetServer.php?imagePath=...&var2=val&...

Comment: I'm using the Kirby CMS framework (it's PHP). The snippetServer.php file is just a very short PHP snippet.

Comment: I think you should isolate your problem: please check from your browser if its working with the simple GET request as I suggested above, otherwise is a jQuery problem which I think is unlikely in your case. Please look also where it wants you to redirect: mostly you will see an error page (a misspelled word, someother error)!

Comment: Is the redirect happening because it can't find the file, thinks the file moved, or because there's something wrong in the file? I haven't been able to affect the results with anything I've put into the snippetServer.php file. The call just never seems to get to snippetServer.php. The way Kirby CMS works, I can't call that file direct from the server, Kirby wants to grab the url and route it.

Comment: Whats the output of: http://localhost/assets/api/snippetServer.php?imagePath=<put_here_theImagePath>&clientPath=<put_here_theClientPath> and where it wants you to redirect?

Comment: I finally figured it out. It wasn't an AJAX or jQuery problem at all. It had to do with the framework I'm using (Kirby) - I shouldn't have been calling the template directly. Thanks for the comments, everyone.